# clang bug? Ambiguous function call compilation errors, yet there is no amiguity present

Tags: c++, templates, clang, friend

I have been bashing my head in for the past 9 hours.

I just got a new MacBookPro with the M3 processor (ARM), and installed all command-line tools, including `clang`, with `xcode-select --install`.

`clang++` is mistaking a `friend` declaration within a class and its definition outside the class as two distinct functions, despite having identical signatures.

I have reduced my problematic code as much as humanly possible to expose the cause of the compilation errors. I am sure this means `clang` is faulty, as I've been writing C++ for a while and have never run into this - the code also compiles fine on my other Macs and Linux instance.

I deleted and reinstalled all the command-line tools. Same stuff.

Here is the bare-bones code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace gml {
    template <typename T>
    concept Numeric = requires (T value) {
        T{};
        // lots of stuff...
    };
    template <Numeric T>
    class tensor {
        // lots more stuff...
    public:
        tensor() = default; // constructs an empty tensor
        template <Numeric U, Numeric V>
        friend bool operator==(const tensor<U>&, const tensor<V>&);
    };
    template <Numeric U, Numeric V>
    bool operator==(const tensor<U>& t1, const tensor<V>& t2) {
        return true;
    }
}

int main() {
    gml::tensor<long double> t;
    gml::tensor<long double> t3;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "t == t3: " << (t == t3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

... and here is the exact compilation error I get from the above:

```
test.cpp:26:54: error: use of overloaded operator '==' is ambiguous (with operand types 'gml::tensor<long double>' and 'gml::tensor<long double>')
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "t == t3: " << (t == t3) << std::endl;
                                                   ~ ^  ~~
test.cpp:15:21: note: candidate function [with U = long double, V = long double]
        friend bool operator==(const tensor<U>&, const tensor<V>&);
                    ^
test.cpp:18:10: note: candidate function [with U = long double, V = long double]
    bool operator==(const tensor<U> &t1, const tensor<V> &t2) {
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I would most appreciate it if someone could give me some insight on this.

P.S., I compiled using `clang++ -std=c++20 test.cpp -o test`, and running `clang++ --version` prints:

```
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Possibly Apple clang only. Works with gcc, clang, msvc here: https://godbolt.org/z/PG1zTedaz

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yup, that's what I feared. Guess I might have to get a different compiler!

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters [give homebrew a look](https://brew.sh/). And don't bang your head so much. Save that for an Ozzy concert.

Comment: @user4581301 hehe... indeed, I should save the head-banging for when it's really needed ;) and homebrew worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a apple-clang bug and the program is well-formed. All three other compilers(gcc, clang and msvc) [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/c7d3vdjcq) the program just fine.

As a workaround for apple-clang, you can just define the friend template inside the class template:

```
namespace gml {
    template <Numeric T>
    class tensor {
        
    public:
        //other code as before
        template <Numeric U, Numeric V>
        friend bool operator==(const tensor<U>&, const tensor<V>&) //provide definition here inside class
        {
            return true;  
        }
    };
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That workaround would, indeed, have worked, but there were also other compilation errors that I didn't even want to get into....

I got Homebrew and installed `g++`, and everything is fine-and-dandy now.

Cheers!

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters You're welcome. Usually, writing/defining the friend function is the simplest option that many prefer as it simplify(readable etc) things in addition to making the code less error-prone.